# Strange NoSuchFileException when trying to read a file

Tags: java, resources

```
File privateKeyFile = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("privateKey").getFile());
```

successfully gives me a keyFile. If I now list the path with:

```
privateKeyFile.toPath()
```

debug successfully shows me a path to the file:

> file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/xx/xyz/abc/encryption/1.0/encryption-1.0.jar!/privateKey

--

However, as soon as I try and read that file with

```
Files.readAllBytes(privateKeyFile.toPath())
```

I get

> Method threw 'java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException' exception.

This is really confusing, and I've tried changing the `getResource()` to various things like `getResource("/privateKey");` - yet that errors a lot sooner, actually a NPE right when trying to create a `new File()`, so the file MUST exist as I've shown above??

Comment: A file lives on the file system. Your resource is inside a jar file. So it's not a file. Don't use file IO to read resources from the classpath, located inside your jar file, since they are **not** files. If you need a URL, then getResource() gives you that. If you need bytes, then getResourceAsStream() gives you that.

Comment: @JBNizet I was following this guide https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/read-file-from-resources-folder/. Can you recommend another?

Comment: No. But the javadoc is your friend.

Comment: The getFile() method of URL *is not* guaranteed to return a valid file name.  It just returns part of a URL, with all the percent-escapes intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to replies, I now use this code successfully

```
//working
InputStream publicKeyStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("publicKey");
toByteArray(privateKeyStream));
```

I initally tried the other method that was given, but that resulted in a BadPaddingException, likely due to not fully reading the file

```
//The incorrect code:

byte[] array = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(array);
```

Answer (score -1):

The constructor of `File` does not care if the path string actually points to an existing file, so do not rely on that to check whether the file is there or not. Use `privateKeyFile.exists()` instead (it returns `true` if the file exists). From what I see, the file really isn't there or the path you give isn't correct, so `exists()` should return false.

Comment: This is not actually correct. File only actually access files that are in the filesystem. The OP is asking to access a file inside of the Jar file, which is a different process.

Comment: Indeed it is a different process, but still, nothing prevents you from passing an incorrect path to the File() constructor, as I said. In fact, the problem only arises when you actually try to access said file. What I said is correct, but I understand that I didn't provide a solution.

Answer (score -3):

Since the file is inside of your Jar, it is not recognized by Java as an actual "file". Because of this, you have to read it a little differently. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20389418/4254252), you might read it something like this:

```java
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("privatekey");

byte[] array = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(array);
```

Or of you're in Java 9+, it could look like this:

```java
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("privatekey"); 
byte[] array = in.readAllBytes();
```

**Edit:**
Since some people wanted an example with the entire source code of the read function, here you go:

```java
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("privatekey"); 

List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
while(in.available() > 0) {
    byte[] b = new byte[in.available()];
    in.read(b);
    bytes.addAll(b);
}

byte[] array = (byte[]) bytes.toArray();
```

Comment: `available()` doesn't return the total numbers of bytes that ca be read from the stream. Your code is incorrect. It could work, but also could fail readin all the bytes.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available() "Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read"

Comment: Returns **an estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream **without blocking**. So, it's an estimate, and the estimate is the number of bytes that can be read **without blocking**. So, as I said, it's clearly not the total number of bytes that can be read from the stream.

Comment: I understand your whole spiel, but this is just an example. It's not the actual implementation. Just trying to explain how it could be read.

Comment: And why do you explain it with incorrect code instead of explaining it with correct code, or with no code at all if you can't write it correctly?

Comment: I don't think you understand that this is a proof of concept. The code is not wrong. It will work just fine, just *might* not read the *entire* file. If the OP chooses to implement it, reading until there are no more bytes to read, so be it. But this code will work, and answers the OP's question.

Comment: It **is** clearly wrong. I just pasted the documentation proving that it is wrong. BTW, there is no toByteArray() method either, so the second snippet wouldn't even compile. I don't think you understand that people copy and paste code, and that you just encourage them to introduce buggy code in their code base.

Comment: As said, "Or of you're in Java 9+": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes-- And what I am doing is answering the OP's question, not writing their entire program for them. Don't encourage people to just ask for other people to write their code for them. I am encouraging actual thinking, and learning.

Comment: No, you don't. And don't try to trick me: you deliberately copied a truncated sentence from the javadoc, and now you're claiming that you used readAllBytes() from the beginning, although you used toByteArray(), which doesn't exist: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55536382/revisions. If you want to encourage thinking, then don't post buggy code. Just tell that you can read the bytes from the returned input stream. I said that in my previous comment: *explaining it with correct code, or with no code at all*.

Comment: Oh, and the code you posted is extremely inefficient, and incorrect.

Comment: Hahaha, it's hilarious. Now the OP confirms it copied and pasted your code. So uch for "encouraging actual thinking, and learning". See: I'm quite experienced here. I know that posting incorrect code is never a good idea. Even if you surround it with warnings that it's just a POC.